# Difference between keyclock standalone version and core version?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I want to know the difference between 'Keycloak core version' and 'Keycloak stand-alone version'.Can anyone explain this

Comment: Can you specify exactly where and what are this versions you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

`Keycloak Standalone` is the complete distribution that constitute the server, `keycloak core` is just a library (a jar) which is part of the distribution.